# Is blurring or fading out an SVG path possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

Is it possible to blur or fade out an SVG path? I have a bunch of lines that I would ideally like to fade out at the beginning or end (i.e. just on one side), or at the very least blur them so it looks like one half is more in focus than the other.

If it's not possible, how could I go about changing the SVG to make it possible?

```js
var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
bodyElement.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouseDirection, false);

var xDirection = "";
var yDirection = "";

var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 0;

function getMouseDirection(e) {
  if (oldX < e.pageX) {
    xDirection = "right";
  } else {
    xDirection = "left";
  }
  if (oldY < e.pageY) {
    yDirection = "down";
  } else {
    yDirection = "up";
  }
  oldX = e.pageX;
  oldY = e.pageY;
}

var tl;

$('g')
.on('mouseover', function() {
  tl = new TimelineLite();
  if (yDirection === "down") {
    tl.to($(this), 1, {
      y: 10
    });
  }
  if (yDirection === "up") {
    tl.to($(this), 1, {
      y: -10
    });
  }
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
  tl = new TimelineLite();
  tl.to($(this), 1, {
    y: 0,
    x: 0
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.f0 {
  filter: url(#f0);
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

.f1 {
  filter: url(#f1);
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.f2 {
  filter: url(#f2);
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.f3 {
  filter: url(#f3);
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.line {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg height="480" version="1.1" width="640" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="f1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="f2">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="f3">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S538,357,192,108" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S538,357,192,108" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S626,299,507,115" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f1" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S626,299,507,115" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S620,182,612,189" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S620,182,612,189" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S55,480,558,56" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f2" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S55,480,558,56" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S654,86,533,328" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f1" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S654,86,533,328" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S397,248,466,162" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f3" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S397,248,466,162" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S651,181,569,111" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f3" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S651,181,569,111" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S599,394,220,338" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line f0" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S599,394,220,338" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxKvMj

Comment: Do you want a progressive blur along the actual path of the path or do you just want e.g. just the right half of the path's bounding box to be blurred? The first is extremely difficult without chopping your path into sub-paths with different size blurs applied. The second is very easy. (If you want the first, you might be better off using Canvas.)

Comment: @MichaelMullany The first would be ideal. I have no idea how to go about programmatically chopping it into pieces though, and I feel like that would also be a significant performance hit.

Comment: @MichaelMullany What about a gradient fade to transparent along the paths? Is that possible?

Comment: If you just want a fade out, then there is a kind of hacky method using stroke-dash-array and a filter. I've added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to hack a progressive blur along a path by abusing stroke-dash-array and opacity manipulation within an SVG filter. Basically, you carefully construct a stroke dash array of increasing spaces, then use a large blur to "fill in the gaps". Then you boost the opacity using a component transfer and then use the original graphic to mask out the overflow. Note you must first draw your path in white (or your background color) and then the stroke dashed path over it so you have the proper selection for compositing. For a general solution, you'd need to construct the stroke-dash array and the filter using JavaScript because it and the stdDeviation you want to use are going to be dependent on the path length.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" viewBox="0 0 1600 1200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="fade-out">
      
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="16" result="blur-source"/>
    
      <feComponentTransfer result="fader">
        <feFuncA type="gamma" exponent=".5" amplitude="2"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
          
      <feComposite operator="in" in="fader" in2="SourceGraphic"/>    
  
    </filter>
  </defs>

<g filter="url(#fade-out)">
   <path d="M200,300 Q400,50 600,300 T1000,300" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke="white"/> 
  
  <path d="M200,300 Q400,50 600,300 T1000,300"
        fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="10,1,8,3,8,5,7,7,7,9,6,11,6,13,5,15,5,17,5,19,5,21,5,23,5,25,5,27,5,29,5"/> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.. Using css3 `keyframes` like in this tutorial:

https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/

```js
var gs = $('g');

function fade(index) {
  gs.eq(index).css('opacity', Math.random());
  setTimeout(function(){
    fade(++index);
  }, 500);
}

fade(0);
```

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}

g {
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .5s ease;
}

g:hover {
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="480" version="1.1" width="640" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="10" y="10">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S538,357,192,108" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S538,357,192,108" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S626,299,507,115" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S626,299,507,115" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S620,182,612,189" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S620,182,612,189" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S55,480,558,56" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S55,480,558,56" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S654,86,533,328" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S654,86,533,328" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S397,248,466,162" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S397,248,466,162" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S651,181,569,111" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S651,181,569,111" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="hitbox" fill="none" stroke="transparent" d="M11,163S599,394,220,338" stroke-width="5"></path>
    <path class="line" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" d="M11,163S599,394,220,338" stroke-width="1"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Update** Now the snippet is present ,delay, `fade` at the start **and** fade on `:hover` with **your** `SVG`. Hopefully that's you are looking for.

Comment: The OP says they want different parts of the line to fade so some would be sharp and the rest faded. This answer doesn't do that.

Comment: You are right. Apparently I didn't understand the question very well. I was updated my answer. I hope that now I did understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do lot of things using `feGaussianBlur` filter (as you did in the pen) and css `animation`. In [this pen](http://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/d7b764375b07e6370941f5f911aa99b0/?editors=1100) there is an example, creating something like *depth of field* using different filters.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to get progressively more blurry along each path to give it a sort of focus-to-fade effect along each line. But this is nice, and thank you for the depth of field suggestion.